# "No Action Needed" stays greyed out if a flag is retracted in the Late Answers review queue

Tags: discussion, bug, review-queues, late-answers, bug-reporting-process

#### Explanation

In Late Answers Review Queue:

Found that if you flag once, then retract the flag, the button status won't roll back.

---

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Should it? What's the difference?

You did some stuff, you ultimately decided against it. This suggests that this wasn't a trivial case and "I'm done" is justified.

These two buttons look like they do completely the same thing, so unless they do not under the hood (which is something that only developers can tell us), it doesn't matter which one you press.